# After DataTable reload most functions returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am getting a weird error after reloading dataTable, most functions returns null. 
I tried `table.fnDestroy` and then `table.datatable()` but no luck.

```
var oTable = $('#sample_table').dataTable();

var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow); //works
```

After table reload

```
var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow); //returns null
```

Here is a test case showing the issue : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smith000monday/GXjks)

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables keeps track of the data internally, so it is unaware of external changes made to the table elements. Use the provided API to reload data into DataTables.

I would initialize DataTables with some options that specify how to render the Edit column using the mRender callback:

```
var oTable = $('#sample_editable_1').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "aTargets": [4],
        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            return '<a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>';
        }
    }]
});
```

Now in your reload callback, instead of replacing the body of the table you can use fnClearTable and fnAddData:

```
$('body').on('click', '#reload', function () {
    //this is where ajax will be added
    var theData = ['New', 'New', 'New', 'New', null];
    var theTable = $('#sample_editable_1').dataTable();
    theTable.fnClearTable();
    theTable.fnAddData(theData);
});
```

Comment: Why is reinitialize the table after the external change not working? `$('#sample_editable_1 >tbody').replaceWith(ajaxHtml)`
          `oTablePart.dataTable();`

Comment: While I am unsure of why you are still directly manipulating the DOM, you can pass the option 'bDestroy':true on reinit. oTablePart.dataTable({'bDestroy':true});